# Excluding a value from an array of data

Tags: php, object, filtering, blacklist

Within my `in_array` is there away that I can exclude specific terms from `$row->guestEmail`?

For example, `@example.com` and `example1.com` are forbidden substrings for the `$row->guestEmail` values.

Here's what I've tried:

```
foreach ($json->data as $row) {   
    if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails)
            && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate))== date('Y-m-d')) {
        $guests[] = array(
            'FirstName'      => $row->guestFirstName,
            'LastName'       => $row->guestLastName,
            'email'          => $row->guestEmail,
            'country'        => $row->guestCountry,
            'check-in_date'  => $row->startDate,
            'check-out_date' => $row->endDate,
        );
        $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    }
}
```

Comment: you mean you dont want example and exampl1.com included in the array?

Comment: What data is in `$emails`?

Comment: It should already work with your actual code `!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails)`. Have you put the emails to be excluded in the `$emails array` ?

Comment: You could filter to get only data you need to be iterable. For example use  `array_filter` before using foreach to `$json->data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a flexible solution that will allow you to expand your blacklist of emails, you can use `preg_match()` with a dynamic regex pattern based on your array of disqualified emails.

The `\Q...\E` syntax ensures that the symbols within the pattern a treated `literally`.  This is the same effect as `preg_quote()` (without the function call).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PA7qc))

```
$objs = (object)[
    'data' => [
        (object)['guestEmail' => 'bad@example.com'],
        (object)['guestEmail' => 'okay@goodstuff.com'],
        (object)['guestEmail' => 'nope@example1.com']
    ]
];

$blacklist = ['@example.com',  'example1.com'];
$regex = '~\Q' . implode('\E|\Q', $blacklist) . '\E~';

foreach ($objs->data as $row) {
    if (!preg_match($regex, $row->guestEmail)) {    
        $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
    }
}

var_export($emails);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'okay@goodstuff.com',
)
```

If you don't like the idea of regex, you can iteratively call `stripos()` for every element in the blacklist.  `stripos()` will perform better than `substr_count()` because `substr_count()` will keep reading the string to the end (trying to give an accurate count of the number of found strings).  `stripos()` will stop as soon as it finds the first occurrence -- this is optimal code design.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GKsiU))

```
foreach ($objs->data as $row) {
    foreach ($blacklist as $forbidden_string) {
        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $forbidden_string) !== false) {
            continue 2;
        }
    }
    $emails[] = $row->guestEmail;
}
// same result as first snippet
```

Comment: @Jess `in_array()` is not a good function to call when you want to make partial matches.  For this solution to be expandable, you'll need to use a dynamic regex pattern or iterated `stripos()` calls to block certain domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this :

```
if (!in_array($row->guestEmail, $emails)
            && date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->endDate))== date('Y-m-d') && substr_count($row->guestEmail, 'example.com') < '1' && substr_count($row->guestEmail, 'example1.com') < '1') {

//your code
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Ask yourself _why_ you chose `substr_count()` and if you can find a simpler/lighter function to call.  Also ask yourself what good the `in_array()` condition is.  Another consideration is maintainability -- do you want to the OP to keep writing out `substr_count()` calls for every value in the blacklist?

Comment: Well, if we just want to remove specific mails like abc@example.com then it's easy. Just use $excludeArray method. But if we want to hide based on example.com OR example1.com we have to check these string in every mail. That's my context.

Comment: It seems you don't know a better way, I'll post something soon.